# Remove update notification in Unity indicator after xubuntu-desktop installation (12.04)

Tags: unity, xfce, notification-area, xubuntu

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 using Unity. To try it out, I installed the xubuntu-desktop package. Ever since I have a orange or red update notification (see attachment) in my Unity indicator panel, telling me about recommended and security updates, respectively.

**Q: How can I disable the notifications?**

**What i expect to happen:** There is an option to show these updates when you press the update notification. I disabled it and thought it wouldn't show again after a reboot. In addition, I ran *dconf-editor* and manually checked if the option to hide updates is enabled.

**What happened instead:** The update notifications are still there, the only way to get rid of them is to do the updates.

[image: Update Notification]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is a solution or just a workaround to your problem , but you can disable the update-notifier from startup applications. I think you will not receive anymore update-notifications then.

Open a terminal and give this command

```
sudo sed -i 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' -i /etc/xdg/autostart/update-notifier.desktop
```

Then try to disable it from startup applications and see if your problem solved.

**OR**

take a look inside `/etc/xdg/lxsession` and see if is something there related to update-notifier

Comment: I tried both approaches, neither seems to work. unfortunately the first command, albeit successfully changing `NoDisplay=true` to `NoDisplay=false`, does not show any effect. In `/etc/xdg/lxsession` I have two folders (Lubuntu & Lubuntu-Netbook), I renamed both, although I couldn't find any relation to update-notifier.

Comment: The effect of first command is to see the entry of update.notifier in startup applications , because is hidden by default. See now in startup applications and disable (un-mark) the entry.

Comment: I should have read your answer more closely, you are right, upon entering the above command a new entry "Update notifier" appears in "Startup applications". Once disabled, on the next reboot the notification is gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I removed these by removing the package: 'package-update-indicator'

I.e. `sudo apt remove package-update-indicator`

You can check if this is the culprit by seeing if it is running:

```
ps aux | grep package-update-indicator
```

and then killing the process.