# Turning off screensaver in Unity after installing xubuntu-desktop 12.10

Tags: unity, compiz, xfce, screensaver, xubuntu

I'm on Ubuntu 12.10. I installed the xubuntu-desktop package to see if I would like it and determined I would prefer to keep using unity. Ever since I did that I've been running into certain issues when using unity. I never had a screensaver before, but now there is one and I can't seem to turn it off or configure it from the settings menu.

Coming back from the screen saver also results in a compiz error message sometimes. I also have a new update notification icon as mentioned in [this related question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213593/remove-update-notification-in-unity-indicator-after-xubuntu-desktop-installation)

How do I turn off the screensaver? I'd like to remove the package completely if I could.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove xscreensaver
```

Comment: Do I have to manually remove all the extra things xubuntu-desktop installed now? Seems like apt-get remove --purge xubuntu-desktop didn't touch its dependencies.

Comment: @Blitzkev Did removing xscreensaver work? Yes, you have to manually remove the extra things because xubuntu-desktop is just a meta package. Solutions here: http://askubuntu.com/search?q=remove+xubuntu

Answer (score 0):

There are screensaver settings also in x-system. You can use terminal to turn screensaver/blanking off by command: `xset s 0 0` (times in seconds, 0 means off) 
and you can turn power management off by command: `xset -dpms` and on by `xset +dpms`

Default setting for saver are:`xset s 600 600`  (=10 minutes as you may have noticed).

If you remove or replace xscreensaver or gnome-screensaver these setting can still turn you display off. You may want to look the curret settings by command:  `xset q`