# Ubuntu Update Notifier keeps showing

Tags: 18.04, updates, notification

The Update Notifier applet persistently shows that updates are required in Ubuntu 18.04 (normally displaying that there are, for example, two updates available)

[image]

When I then select **Install all updates** I usually get the following
[image]

Have not resolved the issue, but have been able to disable/hide the applet as per [Remove update notification....](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213593/remove-update-notification-in-unity-indicator-after-xubuntu-desktop-installation)
Open a terminal and give this command

```
sudo sed -i 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' -i /etc/xdg/autostart/update-notifier.desktop
```

Then try to disable it from startup applications - *uncheck **Update Notifier***
[image]
Any better solution will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you saying that your Ubuntu system pestered you to install updates, but then didn't install anything? Or failed with some kind of error?  Or pestered you daily when you would have preferred, say, weekly? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Try: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.