# What is the orange star icon with arrow/exclamation symbol on the panel in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04

A red explosion symbol with an exclamation mark appearred on the top bar and then this amber explosion with an arrow, which is shown in the screenshot.

[image]

I can't find out what they are for or signifying. Help welcome.

Comment: In my case it was "synaptic package manager" telling about broken packages.

Answer (score 4):

This is the Update Notifier signifying that there are updates ready for your system. If you click on it, you'll get some options about these updates, similar to the ones in this screenshot (taken from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149772/ubuntu-update-notifier-keeps-showing)):

[image: update options]

Searching for "software-update" icons in `/usr/share/icons/`, I found (based on the icons' names) that the red explosion icon [image: software-update-urgent.png] is used to signify *urgent* updates, while the orange explosion icon [image: software-update-available.png] signifies *available* updates.

Comment: thank you. The red exclamation mark, replaced by the amber arrow, appeared for the first time ever and disappeared when I restarted my computer. I tried clicking on them but nothing ever happened. Just odd - I am pleased they are nothing serious, I update often so hopefully won't see them again! Where could I find info about these type of icons- couldn't finds anything on  18.04